# How to do linear regression on a pcolormesh plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, least-squares

I'm trying to run a least square algorithm to fit a line into my data.

This code is similar to my problem; 'z' is a 50 in 50 matrix, and I want to fit a line through data which have a power more than 0.25 for example. (By power meaning the color bar on the right)

I was wondering how can I fit the best line through the power? In my data, x axis is time, y axis is frequency, and z is the power. 
Also, my data is more uniform, so power over 0.25 is nearly linear.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter

# Generate data for the plot
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 51)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 51)
r = np.random.RandomState(42)
z = gaussian_filter(r.random_sample([50, 50]), sigma=5, mode='wrap')
z -= np.min(z)
z /= np.max(z)

# Generate the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cmap = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z)
fig.colorbar(cmap)
plt.show(fig)
```

I just needed some guidance on how to plot the best fitting line.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to find the best fitting line, and plot it to the same axis:

```
thresh = 0.25

# location where z > thresh
# x,y,z are the same as yours
xc, yc = np.where(z > thresh)

# find best fit line
a, b = np.polyfit(x[xc],y[yc], 1)

# Generate the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# show color mesh
cmap = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z, vmin=thresh)

# plot the line
ax.plot(x,a*x + b, c='w')

# set the y limit to avoid line outside of the mesh
ax.set_ylim(y.min(), y.max())

fig.colorbar(cmap)
plt.show(fig)
```

Output:

[image]